# Text slider on easyer way

Tags: javascript, html

I try on a easyer way to do my own text slidder on my way to learn js but I don't have any ideea how to continue. On my console there are my array devided by 5 (I need to see just 5 by 5 not all in one page). Now I try to link my first object (that contain 5 elements) with my first bullet, then second object with my second bullet, so on...
I would like when you make click on first bullet, to see 1-5 articols, when you click on second bullet, to see 5-10 articole, so on. I need my "active" class that is now on every bullet to appear just on the bullet text activ you see it. Al last, I need that slider to go byself every 5 seconds to move from first bullet, to second, to third, so on.
If you may help me it will be greate :)

```js
(function(){
 
 var box = document.getElementById("box");
 var bulletContainer = document.getElementById("bullet-cont");
 doRequest();
 
 setInterval(function(){
  doRequest();
 }, 180000);
 
 function doRequest(){
  $.getJSON("https://gafwebmaster.github.io/json/json2.json", function(data){
   afiseaza(data);
   arata(getBulletsNumber(data));
   newsDevide(data, 5);
  }
 )}
 
 function afiseaza (ceva) {
  box.innerHTML = "";
  var continut = "";
  for (i=0; i<ceva.news.length; i++){
   var stire = ceva.news[i];
   continut = "<div class='bullet'></div>";
   continut += "<h2>" + stire.title + "</h2>";
   continut += "<p>" + stire.details + "</p>";
   continut += "</div>";
   box.innerHTML += continut;
  }
 }
 
 function getBulletsNumber(calculare){
  return calculare.news.length / 5;
 }
 
 function arata(bullets){
  bulletContainer.innerHTML = "";
  for (i=0; i<bullets; i++){
   bulletContainer.innerHTML += '<div class="bullet active"></div>';   
  }
 }
 
 function newsDevide(ourData, nr) {
        var a = [];
        var counter = nr;
        for (var i = 0; i < ourData.news.length; i += nr) {
            a.push(ourData.news.slice(i, counter));
            counter += nr;
        }
        counter = nr;
        for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            console.log(a[j]);
        }
        return a;
    }
})()
```

```css
/*Css reset*/
#home html,
#home body,
#home h1,
#home h2,
#home div,
#home section,
#home p{
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*General style*/
body *{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 font-size: 16px;
}

#home {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
}

#home h1{
 font-size: 1.3rem;  
 padding: 10px 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#home h2{
 color: #0f5959;
 font-size: 1.1rem; 
}

#home p{
 color: #638ca6;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
}


#home section{
 max-width: 280px;
 margin: 0 auto; 
}

#home #box{
 border: 1px solid #0f5959; 
 margin-top: -1px;
 padding: 20px;
}

#home #topWidget{
 border: 1px solid #0f5959;
 position: relative;
}

#home .latestNew{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#home #topWidget div.nav{
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 right: 20px;
}

#home #topWidget .bullet{
 background:#bfd70e;
 border-radius:50%;
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 border:1px solid #679403; 
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

#home #topWidget .selected{
 background:#666;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Widget Code</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>  
 </head>
 <body id="home">
  <section id="content">   
   <div id="topWidget">
    <h1>Latest news</h1>
    <div class="nav" id="bullet-cont"></div>
   </div>
  <div id="box"></div>
  </section>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to figure out what you're stuck on and ask a specific question.

Comment: My question is about how to continue to get the result or if there are any easier way to do my text slidder working

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a code writing or review service